# a clientside_callback shows error: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply') when app updated until page is reloaded

Tags: javascript, plotly-dash

I'm working on a plotly dash app where a number of local images are shown. I would like to be able to display them in a larger size so I tried to open a new window with a clientside_callback. The code shown below works well except when I change the url of the image; then the following error is triggered: `Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')` The error disappears if I reload the page however that is something I would like to avoid. Do you have any suggestions?

MWE:

```
import dash
from dash import dcc, html, Input, Output, State


app = dash.Dash(__name__)

image_url = 'https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/1900x800'
# image_url = 'https://source.unsplash.com/user/c_v_r/100x100'
app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Button('Show Image in New Window', id='show-image-button'),
    html.Div(id='hidden-content', style={'display': 'none'}),
])

app.clientside_callback(
    """
    function(n_clicks) {
        if (n_clicks > 0) {
            var imageUrl = '%s';
            var myWindow = window.open("", "", "width=600,height=400");
            myWindow.document.write("<img src='" + imageUrl + "' alt='Image'>");
            myWindow.focus();
        }
        return "";
    }
    """ % image_url,
    Output('hidden-content', 'children'),
    Input('show-image-button', 'n_clicks'),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run_server(debug=True, port=8051)

# Error when changing image_url: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')
```

There is a similar [post on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70834115/i-have-plotly-dash-app-and-get-this-error-cannot-read-properties-of-null-read) but I don't know how (and if) the provided answer would work on my case. Thanks